# "VoiceAge" Error while using pyttsx3 module to add voice to statements

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, chatbot, chatterbot

I was basically developing a chatbot with the help of chatterbot. Now to add voice to the response given by bot, i used pyttsx3 module but eventually it end up like this.
i even tried implementing this module it other voices as it shows that there 3 voices available.

```
engine = pp.init()
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)#


def speak(word):
  engine.say(word)
  engine.runAndWait()
```

for this code i got this error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 engine = pp.init()
----> 2 voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
      3 print(voices)
      4 engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)#

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py:146, in Engine.getProperty(self, name)
    128 def getProperty(self, name):
    129     """
    130     Gets the current value of a property. Valid names and values include:
    131 
   (...)
    144     @raise KeyError: When the property name is unknown
    145     """
--> 146     return self.proxy.getProperty(name)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py:173, in DriverProxy.getProperty(self, name)
    164 def getProperty(self, name):
    165     '''
    166     Called by the engine to get a driver property value.
    167 
   (...)
    171     @rtype: object
    172     '''
--> 173     return self._driver.getProperty(name)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py:69, in NSSpeechDriver.getProperty(self, name)
     66 @objc.python_method
     67 def getProperty(self, name):
     68     if name == 'voices':
---> 69         return [self._toVoice(NSSpeechSynthesizer.attributesForVoice_(v))
     70                 for v in list(NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices())]
     71     elif name == 'voice':
     72         return self._tts.voice()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py:69, in <listcomp>(.0)
     66 @objc.python_method
     67 def getProperty(self, name):
     68     if name == 'voices':
---> 69         return [self._toVoice(NSSpeechSynthesizer.attributesForVoice_(v))
     70                 for v in list(NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices())]
     71     elif name == 'voice':
     72         return self._tts.voice()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py:64, in NSSpeechDriver._toVoice(self, attr)
     60 except KeyError:
     61     lang = attr['VoiceLanguage']
     62 return Voice(attr['VoiceIdentifier'], attr['VoiceName'],
     63              [lang], attr['VoiceGender'],
---> 64              attr['VoiceAge'])

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_convenience_mapping.py:18, in __getitem__objectForKey_(self, key)
     16 def __getitem__objectForKey_(self, key):
     17     res = self.objectForKey_(container_wrap(key))
---> 18     return container_unwrap(res, KeyError, key)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_convenience.py:134, in container_unwrap(v, exc_type, *exc_args)
    132 def container_unwrap(v, exc_type, *exc_args):
    133     if v is None:
--> 134         raise exc_type(*exc_args)
    135     elif v is _NULL:
    136         return None

KeyError: 'VoiceAge'
```

what can i do next...

Comment: This issue was introduced when I updated my OS from Mac OS Monterey to Mac OS Ventura 13.1

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem today.
A better is to handle the VoiceAge in the nsss.py.
But my solution is more rough, just editing the nsss.py file of pyttsx3, remove the  **,attr['VoiceAge']** part.

[image]

in your situation, you might edit **/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py** at the 64 line.

Then it will work.
More details can be seen at https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/248 .

Comment: it worked for me on macos

Comment: Worked for me on macOS.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the top of the nss.py file and change line 5 to:

```py
from pyttsx3.voice import Voice
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me on macOS.